# Delete duplicates in dropdown list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have hard coded and added items to dropdownlist ie teamsize as 1,2,3 like that.

When i load this dropdownlist for edit/update i get duplicate values like this

1

1

2

3

4... How do i eliminate this duplicate values?

please find the code below

```
         <select name="anesthesia" id="selectAnesthesiaVal" style="width:25%;" class="required safe" AppendDataBoundItems = "false">
          <option value="<?php echo isset($event)?$event->proc_anesthesia_type:"" ;?>"><?php echo isset($event)?$event->proc_anesthesia_type:"" ;?></option><option value="General">General</option>
          <option value="Mac">Mac</option>
          <option value="Spinal/Epidural">Spinal/Epidural</option>
          <option value="Regional">Regional</option>
          <option value="Local">Local</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: What is the code of the 'hard coded dropdownlist'?

Comment: If it is "hard coded", how are you edit/updating it?

Comment: Use jQuery.each() to loop through each element and test to see if another element with the same value exists. If so, use the jQuery.remove() to get rid of it.

Comment: Of course, it might be better to find out how you got duplicate entries in the first place.

Comment: @ben Carey thanks for your reply here i am getting value from database which is in php so how can i do it using jquery. can you help me with code

Comment: Good comment @JeffB. Before proceeding with the jQuery, make sure your php is doing the best job it can. Maybe look at something like this for each option: <option value="<?php echo isset($event)&&$event=='General'?'General':""; ?>"><?php echo isset($event)&&$event=='General'?'General':""; ?></option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use jQuery for this then I would advise placing all of the possible values into an array and looping through them in PHP. Then if the value exists, only place it once.

In addition, if you would like to use jQuery and the PHP is not possible in your circumstances then let me know and I will post up some jQuery.

**UPDATE**

This will do the trick. I have clearly laid out comments to explain what is going on step by step. Hope this helps.

**Please note that it would be much more efficient to do this in PHP**

```
// Set the present object
var present = {};
$('#selectAnesthesiaVal option').each(function(){
    // Get the text of the current option
    var text = $(this).text();
    // Test if the text is already present in the object
    if(present[text]){
        // If it is then remove it
        $(this).remove();
    }else{
        // Otherwise, place it in the object
        present[text] = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that line

`<option value="<?php echo isset($event)?$event->proc_anesthesia_type:"" ;?>"><?php echo isset($event)?$event->proc_anesthesia_type:"" ;?></option>`

add option which correspond to option choosen from select control, i e on first load you see coded list as this line returns empty option, but when you choose actual option this first one gets populated with choosen value

in this case you need to do 2 things
1 remove this line
2 add conditions to each line of hardcoded option and set it to select depending on the value of `$event->proc_anesthesia_type`
and because of 2nd tank you will end up with 6 almost identical conditional statements putting `selected='selected'` to each option

so in order to make the overall code looks pretty i recomend instead of hardcodding options add values to list or even better dictionary and check this condition in a loop